# git and libgit : unable to create file (No such file or directory)

Tags: c++, git

I'm creating a git repository and a commit using libgit2 (in C++). 
It works fine, however, a checkout destroys all the local files.

However they seem to be still present in the repo . That's what I get when I try to look in the repository.

```
Welcome to Git (version 1.8.3-preview20130601)


Run 'git help git' to display the help index.
Run 'git help <command>' to display help for specific commands.

x@x-PC /C/Users/x/Desktop/poiu (master)
$ git log
commit a63cd37ef7d7228053b875e396531d367e2ea745
Author: Unregistered User <unregistered@x.com>
Date:   Fri Oct 25 13:27:21 2013 +0200

    Project Save

x@x-PC /C/Users/x/Desktop/poiu (master)
$ git checkout a63cd37ef7d7228053b875e396531d367e2ea745
D       "db\\32\\879a83081b8d0b4ef41a37b9e28138"
D       "db\\41\\930644af1f4ab6d288bf3d50829558"
D       "db\\48\\3172d42be6ccb80e57071d5aabb584"
D       "db\\80\\0b152a41ba2ef0bc1c55c96add4d33"
D       "db\\c1\\3b1ce3276ed14d7ff7c6ace9b63cf3"
D       "db\\fa\\50e29fe380a8117140463106ae67b1"
Note: checking out 'a63cd37ef7d7228053b875e396531d367e2ea745'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b new_branch_name

HEAD is now at a63cd37... Project Save

x@x-PC /C/Users/x/Desktop/poiu ((a63cd37...))
$ git checkout -f a63cd37ef7d7228053b875e396531d367e2ea745
error: unable to create file db\32\879a83081b8d0b4ef41a37b9e28138 (No such file or directory)
error: unable to create file db\41\930644af1f4ab6d288bf3d50829558 (No such file or directory)
error: unable to create file db\48\3172d42be6ccb80e57071d5aabb584 (No such file or directory)
error: unable to create file db\80\0b152a41ba2ef0bc1c55c96add4d33 (No such file or directory)
error: unable to create file db\c1\3b1ce3276ed14d7ff7c6ace9b63cf3 (No such file or directory)
error: unable to create file db\fa\50e29fe380a8117140463106ae67b1 (No such file or directory)
HEAD is now at a63cd37... Project Save

x@x-PC /C/Users/x/Desktop/poiu ((a63cd37...))
$
```

Now, what's "weird"is that if I create the db\xx directories manually before hand, the checkout -f works.

Even weirder, the whole thing works as-is under MacOSx but not Windows ...

Any idea of what's going on here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ git checkout a63cd37ef7d7228053b875e396531d367e2ea745
D       "db\\32\\879a83081b8d0b4ef41a37b9e28138"
```

See the quotes?  git will use C string literal conventions to display filenames with unusual characters in them.  Your repo records a file with that C string as its name -- backslashes included.

`:`, `\`, and `/` aren't invalid everywhere,

```
$ touch "db\\32\\879a83081b8d0b4ef41a37b9e28138"
$ ls
db\32\879a83081b8d0b4ef41a37b9e28138
$ git add .
$ git ls-files
"db\\32\\879a83081b8d0b4ef41a37b9e28138"
$
```

but they're not portable.

Roughly speaking, Windows filesystems reserve `\` and `:`, Mac, `:`, Unix, `/`.  There may still be systems that reserve `;`.

Comment: Sounds like you nailed it. What separator can I use then to make a commit with gitlib that is portable on win, mac and linux ?

Comment: It's not unusual for libraries to interpret forward slashes as separators regardless of system, unix is doing the moray-eel thing on API's, but I'm not sure which one you're referring to and don't use either (any?) of them myself, sorry.

Comment: Ok, I changed my code, and your solution works. I feel kind of stupid now hehe...anyways, the bounty is yours ! Thank you

Comment: two heads better because stuff like this, today you, tomorrow me. np.

Answer (score 1):

Can you check if you are in MacOSx and in Windows in a detached Head state?

Another idea would be the filesystem differences, maybe you can find something related to this?